# can hibernate hsql automatically map the query result to a class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote a hsql:

```
String queryString = "select t1.a, t1.b, t2.c from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id";
```

and then I have a class:

```
class test{
String a;
String b;
String c
 ....//other getter and setter
}
```

I tried:
List = getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
this doesn't work, when I use test object in jsp page, it will throw out exception.

I have to manually create a test object:

```
List<Object[]> list =  getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
test.seta(list.get(0)[0]);
```

is it possible for hibernate to automatically map the class for me in hsql ?

Comment: Do you have hibernate mapping for table1 and table2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a mapping for both table1 and table2 (see Prashant question above) you can do something like:

```
String queryString = "select t1 from table1 t1
                      inner join t1.table2 t2";
```

After you run the query you should have a list of t1 objects.

```
for(Table1 t1:listOfTable1Objects) {
   t1.getA(); //for example or whatever you want to do with your object.

}
```

Comment: but I didn't map table2 to be a foreign relation with table1

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you do not write a HQL query. You just write a normal SQL query. In HQL, because the hibernate make the mapping from table to class, you cannot make a projection. So, if you write something like

`String query = "FROM Class1 WHERE ome_condition;`

without the SELECT clause, the Hibernate will be able to convert the result in the proper object.

You can see more about this here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

If you dont have a mapping, you may create a auxiliary class for this. Say ResultClass. Then you add @NamedNativeQuery and @SqlResultSetMapping annotations to the class:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="queryHehehe", query="select t1.field1 f1, t2.field2 f2 from table1 t1, table2 t2", resultSetMapping="mappingHehehe")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="mappingHehehe", entities={
    @EntityResult(entityClass=my.clazz.AuxiliaryClass.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name="id", column="f1"),
        @FieldResult(name="other_property", column="f2")
    }),
})
public class AuxiliaryClass {
    public Long id;
    public String other_property;
}
```

I have never used this, but can work. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but there is not a class which contains all fields from table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

If you need a query to return values from multiple tables and create an object of an unmapped class, then you need to either do what you're doing here, or use a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html).

In order to do this with HibernateTemplate, you'll need to change the way you use the template, possibly using `execute(HibernateCallback action)`, as you'll need to convert the sql query to a Criteria as described in [Hibernate Reference Native SQL Chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).

If you do want to try this, you'll probably want to use an `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` or `AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer` rather than writing your own transformer.